# Reading CSV, List length not matching after splitting cell values

Tags: python, list, csv

So, im running into a coding issue (duh) which is involving alot of different components within python (reading a .csv, extracting the values into lists, then manipulating those individual values)

So my code DOES work when I execute the program, however, the number I am expecting to see does NOT match the number that comes out. I put in a validation check just to be sure and i'm off for about 800 entries....UNLESS im missing something - i can't figure out why.

So, there are 1213 rows in this .csv which have 6 values in each row separated by a space.
i.e - A1 has a value of 01 02 03 04 05 06 A2 has a value of 07 08 09 10 11 12 etc...
With each row having 6 values, I should have a total of 7278 individual values.

However, when I execute my code and do a count of the generated list, I get a total of 6409. Which is a difference of 869 values. Unless I am missing something where it is counting, I can't figure out where the missing 869 is. Is it counting spaces, commas from my list?

Now - ONTO the code:

```
with open('hoursWorked.csv', newline='') as inputfile:
    for row in csv.reader(inputfile):
        pwrNumList.append(row[1])

# remove the top title of hours worked in csv file
pwrNumList.pop(0)

# Split the six values in each cell and create a separated number as a seperate value that is in between a space bar
pwrNumSplitLst = [item for sublist in [item.split(" ") for item in pwrNumList] for item in sublist]

print (len(pwrNumSplitLst)) #<---This value is coming out to 6409 when it should be 7278 (1213 * 6)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try to recreate the CSV file from the read data (with same formatting) and use a diff tool to find out which lines are missing. You can then examine these further.

Comment: I had tried replicating your problem, the code broke because the row has only 1 element, and row[1] raised an exception. I had changed this to row[0], then I got the correct output of 7278.

Comment: Provide the first few lines of your file to ensure we understand the format.  It sounds like it has a header row e.g. `Col1,Col2` and 1213 rows following `A1,01 02 03 04 05 06`, `A2,07 08 09 10 11 12`, correct?  I would add code that checks `len(item.split(' ')) == 6`  because every row must not be the correct length.

Answer (score 0):

The commented out code below generates the file as described and the remainder counts it correctly.  Run the script on your file to find rows that don't follow the pattern:

```py
import csv

#with open('hoursWorked.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
#    w = csv.writer(f)
#    w.writerow(['Col1','Col2'])
#    for i in range(1213):
#        w.writerow([f'A{i+1}',f'{i*6} {i*6+1} {i*6+2} {i*6+3} {i*6+4} {i*6+5}'])

pwrNumList = []
with open('hoursWorked.csv', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r) # skip header
    for i,row in enumerate(r,2): # count lines starting at 2
        values = row[1].split()
        if len(values) != 6:
            print(f'row {i} length is {len(values)}')
        pwrNumList.extend(values)

print(len(pwrNumList))
```